# What is the maximum length of a parameter in loadrunner?

Tags: c, loadrunner

I am a beginner in loadrunner. I am working with Loadrunner 12.53. I have recorded one simple which will login to one application and Logout.(I recorded with `user1` login id) I am testing it with different users  say`(user2, user3, user4,..., user10, user11)`. The script is passing successfully till `user9` and it is failing from `user10`. I am getting below error: HTTP-Internal application error
`The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: Error in deserializing body of request message for operation 'ClearCurrentUserFormApplication'. The input source is not correctly formatted.`
All the users are existed in that application. Is it because of the change in length of the parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Record your site with User 10 settings.  Compare to a recording for User9.   The differences in structure will need to be addressed